# How to get specific Column and it's rows(cells) in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I want to get a specific column and its cells and assign a letter to it in the next column.

Code:

```
If Column1.Cell = 0  Then
Column2.Cell(0).Value = "A"
```

Meaning in `Column1`'s first cell, letter "A" must be displayed in `Column2`'s first cell.

But the code isn't working the way I want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear up what you mean. Do you mean if `column1`'s first cell contains a 0 then `Column2`'s first cell needs to be set to A?

If this is the case your if statement is wrong it should be

```
If column1.cell(0) = 0 then
```

I believe

Comment: Yeah that is what I actually mean

Comment: I think the solution I've provided should work although I'm on a train so try it and see

Comment: No it's not working because column does not have the cell attribute in datagridview